# Animate package - output graphic size is smaller than original

Tags: graphics, scaling, animate

I successfully created an animation PDF from mulitple PDF pages by using the `animate` package, but the problem is that the output graphics size is about half the size of the original.

How can I preserve the original size? Any hints?

Here is my `.tex` code for running `pdflatex`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{animate}
\begin{document}
\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop, width=1\linewidth]{1}{file}{1}{13}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just omit any post-scaling options, such as `width` or `scale`. Then the original size, that is the size of the first graphics of the sequence, will be used for the animation.

In your case, `width=1\linewidth` will resize the width of the animation to the line width of the hosting document. This is the largest width I would recommend, as a larger animation would extend into the page margin or beyond, generating `overfull hbox` warning messages. If the result is indeed half the original size, the original size would be far too big to fit into your hosting document. Thus, `width=1\linewidth` seems to be a sensible choice.

Answer (score 5):

if you want the natural width do not use the width setting.

```
\noindent
\makebox[\textwidth]{\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{1}{file}{1}{13}}
```

Comment: thanks for the kind help. i have deleted width=1\linewidth and i got the original size ! but now i have another problem - part of the graphics is shifted to the right, outside the page. i don't understand why this happen because my original pdf does fit it nicely inside a page of A4. when i pdflatex, i did get the message of "Overall hbox (160.89pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 6--7. Anyway, if you know the way to shift the graphics about 3cm left in the final animation pdf, pls tell me ! thks for ur support !

Comment: try `\makebox[\textwidth]{\animate....}`

Comment: Strange. `\includegraphics{file1}` and `\animategraphics{1}{file}{1}{13}` should produce boxes of exactly the same size.

Comment: Put `\noindent\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop,width=\textwidth]{1}{file}{1}{13}` on a line of its own. This will produce an animation which takes up the maximum allowable width without `overfull \hbox` messages.

Comment: \makebox[\textwidth]{\animategraphics[controls,autoplay,loop]{1}{C}{1}{5}} did the trick ! the graphics shift right and now pretty much at the center with original size preserved, thanks !

Comment: I did tried \noindent\animategraphics and the hbox message did disappeared, but the graphics size has agained shrink to half of original. anyway problem is pretty solved, i am happy now, thanks a lot for the support and this wonderful package !

Comment: It seems that your graphics files have a lot of white space (margins) around the graphic. How did you create them? Try to produce graphics with a tightly enclosing  bounding box.

Comment: for your information, the size of my original size pdf is 177.8mm x 177.8mm when i checked with file/property in acrobat reader.

Comment: actually there is hardly any white space margins around all four sides of graphics. i produced the graphics using R and ggplot and grid package i think. i used viewport. i am not too familiar with it but it did generate the pdf ok.

Comment: here are the codes here are the codes:
grid.newpage()
layout <- grid.layout(nrow=3,ncol=2,width=unit(c(3.25,3.25),c("inches","inches")),heights=unit(c(3.25,3.25,0.5),c("inches","inches","inches")))
pushViewport(viewport(layout=layout))
subplot <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row = x,layout.pos.col = y)
print(plot1, vp=subplot(1,1:2))
print(plot2, vp=subplot(2,1))
print(plot3, vp=subplot(2,2))
footnote <- "Report Generated on 2012/1/4"
grid.text(label=footnote, x = 0.5, y = 0.05)
dev.off()

Comment: Your graphics are definitely too large to be embedded unscaled, as well with `\includegraphics` as with `\animategraphics`: original width 177.8mm equals 505.89pt and `\linewidth` equals 345.0pt for an `[a4paper]{article}` document.

Comment: hi how do u work out 177.8mm equals 505.89pt ? just by multiplying a factor?

Comment: `\newlength\tmpdim\setlength\tmpdim{177.8mm}\typeout{\the\tmpdim}`. The difference to `\linewidth` is exactly the `160.89pt` you mentioned in your first comment. Replace `\animategraphics` by `\includegraphics` and you will get the same warning and visual appearance.